# I am unable to push my Node.js with Mongodb backend project on Bluemix. Instance creation is failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk, ibm-cloud

The following the log dump from my cf push :

> 2014-09-09T15:47:35.92+0530 [App/0]   ERR  2014-09-09T15:47:35.97+0530
>   [DEA]     OUT Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
>   2014-09-09T15:47:55.71+0530 [DEA]     OUT Starting app instance (index
>   0) with guid 20dba222-e0e6-453c-96a9-429940bc7002
>   2014-09-09T15:47:57.59+0530 [API]     OUT App instance exited with
>   guid 20dba222-e0e6-453c-96a9-429940bc7002 payload:
>   {"cc_partition"=>"default",
>   "droplet"=>"20dba222-e0e6-453c-96a9-429940bc7002",
>   "version"=>"832505e6-a95d-4696-910e-a8d4a74a7005",
>   "instance"=>"4ff487a75a674aa79b234cc1bd8f9a3d", "index"=>0,
>   "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>0, "exit_description"=>"app
>   instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1410257878} 2014-09-09T

This is how my manifest.yml file looks like :

```
applications:
- name: nodetestSDB
  memory: 128M
  command: node app.js
  services:
  - mongodbnode
```

This is how my package.json file looks like :

```
{
  "name": "nodetest2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.8.6",
    "body-parser": "~1.6.6",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.2",
    "morgan": "~1.2.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.0.1",
    "debug": "~1.0.4",
    "jade": "~1.5.0",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "monk": "*"
  }
}
```

The environment variable in app.js :

```
if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {

      var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
      if (env['mongodb-2.2']) {
        var mongo = env['mongodb-2.2'][0]['credentials'];
      }

    var db = monk(mongo.url);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any more output?  Can you paste a little more code from your app also?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my posts on using MongoDB with Bluemix in my blog. You can also check the code in GitHub abd Devops. Most likely you are not parsing the VCAP_SERVICES right.  I have used both Node.js & NodeExpress

http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2014/07/27/a-bluemix-recipe-with-mongodb-and-node-js/
http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/elements-of-crud-with-nodeexpress-and-mongodb-using-enide-studio/
http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/spicing-up-a-ibm-bluemix-cloud-app-with-mongodb-and-nodeexpress/

Regards
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two different start commands for you app.

In manifest.yml you are using "node app.js" and in your package.json you are using "node ./bin/www".

Try having those two files match and that should help.  Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

app.js:

console.log('VCAP SERVICES: ' + JSON.stringify(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES, null, 4));

var mongoUrl;

if(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {

var vcapServices = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);

for (var svcName in vcapServices) {

```
if (svcName.match(/^mongo.*/)) {

  mongoUrl = vcapServices[svcName][0].credentials.uri;

  mongoUrl = mongoUrl || vcapServices[svcName][0].credentials.url;

  break;

}
```

}

}

else

{

mongoUrl = "localhost:27017/SScheduler";

}

console.log('Mongo URL: ' + mongoUrl);

// Database
var mongo = require('mongoskin');

var db = mongo.db(mongoUrl, {native_parser:true});  -->through bluemix

//var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/nodetest2", {native_parser:true});  -->through local setup

i tried like this and it worked for both local and through bluemix